# Connect to a USB Point of Sale Printer Java API

Tags: java, com, usb

We have built a Point of Sale which is works great. I have already addressed Dot-matrix Printer and Terminal Printer implementations through COM port connection. Is there a Java API to connect to the USB Point of Sale printer?

If not, I recently saw that USB devices can be emulated to virtual COM devices. Is it possible to do this for USB Pos printer? Plus everything should work on linux as well(Since are deployment OS is Fedora).

I already tried to use [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) api but I failed to get it installed on the computer.

Comment: If your OS recognizes the printer and you can print a sample using a text file, then you just need to send a document to the printer using the [Java Print API](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1020-print.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I thought of is to use the COM port writing since Linux detect USB printers with virtual COM ports...